# ida pro: scripting debugger with python fails on step_over/run_to

Tags: ida, debugging, idapython

So I am trying to run an app and collect information at certain points.
No biggie, right? Wrong. Check this simple example:

```
import ida_dbg
ida_dbg.step_over() #or runto()
eax = ida_dbg.get_reg_val("eax")
print("eax: ", eax)
```

throws an exception

> Exception: Failed to retrieve register value

But Individually it works. So if I do ONLY a "ida_dbg.step_over()", that works. And if do ONLY a 'get_reg_val("eax")' that works too.
Only in combination it fails.

Now, you might think this is because step_over only posts a request, but the documentation explicitly says otherwise and provides a request_step_over() for that purpose.

Please, can someone enlighten me and show me how I can step over my program and collect register values after each step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! So despite the function being advertised otherwise it is still async and I have to call

> ida_dbg.wait_for_next_event(ida_dbg.WFNE_SUSP, -1)

Is this the correct solution?